# Как сделать затухание заливки StackPane

Tags: java, javafx

Анимация FillTransition применима только к Shape. Как выкрутиться?

```
StackPane sp = new StackPane();
```

Comment: Не нашёл ничего лучше, чем добавить в sp new Pane() и анимировать его через FadeTransitions